# Can't find build.gradle (Module app) in Android Studio project imported from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-studio, eclipse-adt, package-name

I'm new to android and I imported a project from eclipse.

I need to edit the package name in defaultConfig in build.gradle (Module app) code and I just can't find it anywhere..

Here's a snapshot of the project in AS

[image: Snapshot from my project files in AS]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why that answer wasn't accepted but just to confirm, switching to android view instead of project in the navigation pane  allowed me to access it. Once you do this, you can right click the gradle file in android studio and select "show in explorer" This will let you see how it is stored on your local machine.

Comment: It most probably wasn't accepted because lots of people who ask a question don't care about accepting an answer. This has nothing to do with the quality of an answer. P.S.: you could upvote the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

On the top of the pic you uploaded there's a spinner button for "project", turn it to "android" and you will find module app gradle